# Apache "Testing 123" Page present on domain

Tags: node.js, apache, directory, virtualhost

Morning guys

I previously set up a page for https://www.thealternativedrumschool.com/
The node application was installed, I am just a little confused why I am being directed to the testing page.    ( DIT - This has now been removed, I just dont understand why it cant see my app?

This is the IP http://79.98.30.183:8050/      it seems to work here fine

Here is the conf file details

[image]

It is located in these folders

[image]

Any ideas guys? I have googled the earth out of it but not sure what I am doing wrong

Also I have noticed the sites available has the .conf file in but the sites enabled is empty?

Comment: If you find any solution for this, add it to your answer,